# How to install Distro Astro operating system?

Tags: observational-astronomy, software

I've recently started a project on Galaxy spectroscopy for which I had to use IRAF software. During the search for IRAF software, I came across a platform which said that Distro Astro is a very good OS Amateur astronomer should check out. I have searched the internet for the procedure and am an amateur in OS installation and other stuff.

Does anybody know the detailed procedure of installing the software?

Answer (score 1):

[Distro Astra](http://www.distroastro.org/) is a Linux distribution for Astronomy.

Unless you are very familiar with Linux distributions be vary careful about installing it you main computer. If you have an old computer not being used I would suggest you first installed Distro Astra on that computer.

If it is installed as the only operating system for the computer it will wipe whatever was on the disk prior to installing Distro Astra and you will lose everything that was on that disk.

Being an operating system, once installed, it will make permanent changes to the hard disk drive. It may be possible to have a dual boot system that gives the user the option to use the computer via Distro Astra, or the existing (most likely) Microsoft based operating system originally installed, when the computer is booted.

If you do not have an old computer keep your existing hard disk drive in storage but install a new hard drive for Distro Astra. If the installation of Distro Astra becomes totally messed up you will still have the original hard drive to reinsert and your computer will be as it was prior to dabbling with Distro Astra.

If you have no knowledge of Linux operating systems, find a friend to help you or be prepared to learn, make mistakes and sometimes be very frustrated.

Installing Linux on older computers that utilize a [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) is easier than installing on newer computer that use a [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

Comment: It is also possible to install any unknown and potentially complex OS first on a virtual harddrive, that just runs like a program on your primary OS, and avoids nuking your hard drive. It's just going to be slow. The oracle VirtualBox is a free possibility for this.